# The word demand is verb or noun in my sentence?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

In "Patients and doctors" (Kenneth Walker), it says

> The great advantage of taking medicine is that it makes no demands on the taker beyond that of putting up for a moment with a disgusting taste, and that is what all patients demand of their doctors--to be cured at no inconvenience to themselves.

I think that "demand" in "demand of their doctors" is a verb, instead of a noun, am i right?

Comment: Yes, it's a verb with "all patients" as its subject.

Comment: *...makes no **demands** on....* = (plural) NOUN. *...what patients **demand...*** = VERB. Not quite the same as *Do you want my **help**?* (NOUN) and *I will **help** you* (VERB), because *that* noun usage can't be pluralised to ***helps***.

Answer (score 1):

You are right to say "demand" is a verb. In this case the subject is "all patients". If "demand" were to be a noun:

> The demand for cars has been rising

Answer (score 1):

> ...that is what all patients demand of their doctors...

I add to what @BillJ has rightly  commented, that *demand* in OP's example is a verb.

To use the noun **demands** using OP's example, we need a few modifications.

As the verb would no longer be there in the **what-clause**,  we need to add one, like **are**.

> ...that is what all **patients'** demand**s** of their doctors **are**....

> ...that is what all **patients'** demand**s are** of their doctors....

Please note that I have used the plural **demands**, as @FumbleFingers has rightly said, and the possessive **patients'**.

> demands [ plural ] the difficult things that you have to do:
> The demands of nursing are too great for a lot of people.
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/demand)